# Adding docker cert to new K8s nodes

Tags: docker, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

I am very new to Kubernetes and am working with an eks cluster. I am trying to pull images and I have added a cert to /etc/docker/certs.d// and I am able to pull fine after logging in. However when I create a deployment to deploy apps to my pods, it seems like I have to manually ssh into my EKS nodes and copy over the cert. Otherwise, I am left with a x509 Certificate error. Additionally, if I terminate a node and new nodes are created, those new nodes obviously don't have the cert anymore in which I have to copy over the cert again. Is there a way to configure a secret or configmap so that new nodes will automatically have this cert. I know you can add a mount to a configmap, but it seems like this only works for pods.

Also, what is the best way I can replace these certs for cases where the certs expire (i.e. pulling images from ECR)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **secret** to pull the **docker** and storing the cert in **Kubernetes** level but yes you are right it will work with **POD**. There is no way you can manage or inject at the **node** level.

The only option you are left with to create the **custom AMI** and use that for creating the nodes inside the **EKS** **node** so by default you will be having that **cert** into the Node if scale **up** or **down**.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-custom-linux-ami/